# Union of boxes in $\bar{\mathbb{R}}^3$

Tags: combinatorics

Let $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ denote the extended real line. Let    $[x_1,x_2]\times[y_1,y_2]\times [z_1,z_2]$ represent a generic "box" in  $\bar{\mathbb{R}}^3$:

$$[x_1,x_2]\times[y_1,y_2]\times [z_1,z_2]\equiv \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: x_1\leq x \leq x_2,  y_1\leq y \leq y_2, z_1\leq z \leq z_2\}$$

**The square brackets can also be replaced with round brackets, depending on whether the extreme points of each interval are included.**

Let $\mathcal{A}_1$ be the collection of boxes of the form
$$
(a+b, \infty]\times [-\infty, a]\times [-\infty,b]
$$
for every $(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}^2$.

Let $\mathcal{A}_2$ be the collection of boxes of the form
$$
[-\infty,a+b)\times [a,\infty]\times [b,\infty]
$$
for every $(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}^2$.

Let $\mathcal{A}\equiv \mathcal{A}_1\cup \mathcal{A}_2$.

Consider a box $B$  such that:

(1) $B\notin \mathcal{A}$.

(2) $B$ is not contained in (is not a "sub-box" of) any element of $\mathcal{A}$.

An example of $B$ satisfying 1-2 is
$$
(0.2, \infty]\times [-\infty, 10]\times [-\infty,11]
$$

Or also
$$
[0.2, \infty]\times [-\infty, 10]\times [-\infty,11]
$$

**Question:** can a box $B$ satisfying 1-2 be contained in (be a sub-box of) the union of some elements of $\mathcal{A}$? The union should not necessarily be a finite union of elements of  $\mathcal{A}$.

**Conjecture:** I think the answer to my question is no. I don't know how to prove it, though.
Also, I think that the following holds:
$$
\bar{\mathbb{R}}^3\setminus \{\cup_{D\in \mathcal{A}}D\} = \{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3: x-y-z=0\}
$$
That is: once we remove from $\bar{\mathbb{R}}^3$ the union of the boxes in $\mathcal{A}$, we get a plane. I'm not sure  how to use this information, though.

Comment: If $x_i,y_i,z_i$ are real numbers, it certainly isn’t possible, since every box in $\mathcal A$ is unbounded, and the union of unbounded sets is unbounded.

Comment: Which $A\in\mathcal A$ contains $(0.2,10,11)$ and is contained in $[0.2,+\infty)\times(-\infty,10]\times(-\infty,11]?$

Comment: Do you want a *finite* union of elements of $\mathcal{A}$?

Comment: How many of these open-parens-infinities should be closed-brackets-infinities? e.g. the box $B$ you gave satisfies 1 and 2 but it does not have the form you require (since, say, $(x_2,-,-)$ is not contained in $B$). Also 1 is redundant because no box of the form you gave is in $\mathcal{A}$ (for the same open-closed reason). So I think there is still something wrong in the question.

Comment: I must be missing something: Why would $\bar{\mathbb{R}}^3\setminus \{\cup_{D\in \mathcal{A}}D\}$ be the plane?  I thought it would be empty, i.e. the union is the whole $\bar{\mathbb{R}}^3$.  E.g. $(0,0,0)$ is in the plane and it is also in the $A_1$ box with $a=b=0$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I made confusion with using square versus round brackets. I think I have fixed it now. Please let me know if it is still wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you allow arbitrary combinations of open and closed brackets for $B$, but still restrict the boxes in $\mathcal{A}$ to have open and closed brackets as stated above, then your conjecture is **false** - a counter-example exists due to a technicality.

**Claim:** $B = [0, 1] \times [-1, 0) \times [-1, 0)$ satisfy 1-2.

$B \notin \mathcal{A}$ is obvious.

Next consider whether $B$ can be a sub-box of some $A \in \mathcal{A}_1$.  Because the $x$-range of $B$ is $[0,1]$, we need $a + b < 0$ since any box $A$ has $x$-range $(a+b, +\infty]$.  However this implies $a < 0$ or $b < 0$, which would violate either $B$'s $y$-range or $z$-range.

Finally consider whether $B$ can be a sub-box of some $A \in \mathcal{A}_2$.  Similarly $B$'s $x$-range requires $a+b > 1$, which implies $a > 0$ or $b> 0$, which violate either $B$'s $y$-range or $z$-range. $\square$

However, $B$ does not contain any point in the plane $P: x - y - z = 0$.  Therefore, $B \subset \bigcup_{D\in \mathcal{A}} D$ since the union is everything but the plane.

---

The counter-example relies on the fact that, as defined, the boxes in $\mathcal{A}$ have open and closed brackets a certain way, and the counter-example goes a different way.  I have no doubt that if you allow more kinds of boxes in $\mathcal{A}$, while still omitting the plane $P$, then your conjecture should be true i.e. no counter-example can exist.  In fact I think the proof should be conceptually straightforward (but possibly tedious) via a continuity argument.

---

Added Dec 29: I've been thinking about the new $\mathcal{A}_1, \mathcal{A}_2$ in your comments.  I think the continuity argument would go like something like this: Define function $f(x,y,z) = x - y - z$.  Then it should be easy (but perhaps tedious due to the open/closed brackets case analysis) to show all the following:

- $\bigcup_{D\in \mathcal{A}} D$ is the complement of the plane $P: f(x,y,z) = 0$.
- Every box $B$ (whether it satisfies 1-2 or not) can be classified into one of the following 3 cases:

  - If $f(p) > 0$ for every point $p = (x,y,z) \in B$, then $B$ is a subbox of $A \in \mathcal{A}_1$ with $a = y_2, b = z_2$ and appropriate open/closed brackets.
  - Similarly, if $f(p) < 0$ for every point $p = (x,y,z) \in B$, then $B$ is a subbox of some $A \in \mathcal{A}_2$ with $a = y_1, b = z_1$ and appropriate open/closed brackets.
  - Finally, if there are points $p, q \in B$ s.t. $f(p) \ge 0, f(q) \le 0$, then *by continuity* of $f$ there also exists point $r \in B$ s.t. $f(r) = 0$, e.g. by considering $f$ values along the line segment from $p$ to $q$.  But then $r \in P$ and therefore $B$ cannot be covered by $\bigcup_{D\in \mathcal{A}} D$.

Comment: Thank you and +1. Before accepting your answer, may I ask you the following.
Suppose I define $\mathcal{A}_1$ as all the boxes of these 7 types:  $(a+b,\infty]\times [-\infty,a]\times [-\infty,b]$; $(a+b,\infty]\times [-\infty,a)\times [-\infty,b)$; $(a+b,\infty]\times [-\infty,a]\times [-\infty,b)$; $(a+b,\infty]\times [-\infty,a)\times [-\infty,b]$; $[a+b,\infty]\times [-\infty,a]\times [-\infty,b)$; $[a+b,\infty]\times [-\infty,a)\times [-\infty,b]$; $[a+b,\infty]\times [-\infty,a)\times [-\infty,b)$.

Comment: Similarly, I define $\mathcal{A}_2$ as all the  boxes of these 7 types: $[-\infty, a+b)\times [a,\infty]\times [b,\infty)$; $[-\infty, a+b)\times (a,\infty]\times (b,\infty)$; $[-\infty, a+b)\times [a,\infty]\times (b,\infty)$; $[-\infty, a+b)\times (a,\infty]\times [b,\infty)$; $[-\infty, a+b]\times [a,\infty]\times (b,\infty)$; $[-\infty, a+b]\times (a,\infty]\times [b,\infty)$; $[-\infty, a+b]\times (a,\infty]\times (b,\infty)$.

Comment: In this new environment: (i) Is it still the case that $\bar{\mathbb{R}}^3\setminus \{\cup_{D\in \mathcal{A}} D\}=P$, where $P$ is the plane? (ii) Is my conjecture now correct?

Comment: I think both (i) and (ii) are YES.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty.  I have added a sketch of the continuity argument in the new expanded $\mathcal{A}$ setting.  Hope this finally answers the "real" question you had in mind!  (I feel bad giving a counter-example based on a technicality.)  

And happy new year!  :)